# Adding a dependency for AWS lambda in "edit inline" mode

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to import a package to be used by a lambda in edit inline mode - I use Python.

When running it the following error is reported in the log:

```
Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named boto
```

Is there a way to specify the dependency or my only option is to deploy a zip file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only option is to deploy a zip file. If you edit your function via the inline editor, [your dependencies will be lost](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html):

> If you are writing code that uses other resources, such as a graphics library for image processing, [...] you need to first create the Lambda function deployment package, and then use the console or the CLI to upload the package.

The AWS Console gives an appropriate warning:[image]